# context.fillText with Kinetic.JS V 4.70

Tags: kineticjs

I'm using Kinetic.Shape to create some custom text ( I need gradients fills on the text which is not yet supported by Kinetic.Text ).

I was previously achieving this using context.fillStyle && context.fillText within the drawFunc method and it was working well.

However as of V 4.7.0 the API has changed slightly and the context reference which is passed to drawFunc is now a wrapper around the HTML5 canvas context. This means I can no longer directly call methods such as context.fillText() or context.strokeText().

Is there a way to call these methods using the Kinetic wrapper or can I somehow use the raw canvas context to call them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside drawFunc, you can get the **real** canvas context like this:

```
// the real context

var ctx=this.getContext()._context;
```

So if you're careful not to upset Kinetic by drawing behind its back, you can do this:

[image]

```
var shape = new Kinetic.Shape({
    x:0,  // must be 0
    y:0,  // must be 0
    drawFunc:function(ctx){
          var ctx=this.getContext()._context;
          var grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(100,100,200,200 );
          grad.addColorStop(0, 'orange');   
          grad.addColorStop(1, 'blue');
          ctx.fillStyle = grad;
          ctx.save();
          ctx.font="69px verdana";
          ctx.fillText("Gradient!",10,140);
          ctx.strokeText("Gradient!",10,140);
          ctx.restore();
    }
});
```